# Newtonsoft.json replacing dll while compiling

Tags: c#, json, dll

I have a website which use newtonsoft.json dll. I'm using it for target framework 4 and the version I'd like to have i 6.0.8. 
I have 3 project referencing in cascade.
project A use 6.0.8
project B use 6.0.8 (copying it from A)
project C overwrite it with 4.5 even if it does not have a direct reference to it.

I tried to configure nuget in order to add the reference also to project C, but project C continues to use the wrong version.

here my configuration for the last project (c)

package confing from nuget

```
<packages><package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net40" /> </packages>
```

her the web config section

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

here project B (which is actually working
[image]

Why when I compile and publish my web site the newtonsoft.json dll is overwritten with the wrong version?
can someone help me with this issue?
thank you
Andrea

Comment: In your /bin/debug - is it using the right version?

Comment: No, same behaviour in debug

Comment: try an run rebuild instead of build